# EditText fields showing different keyboards

Tags: java, android, keyboard

So I have 2 edittext fields which to me look the same in my android project.

They are both for decimals.

However the KM one keeps bringing up a keyboard with the option of entering letters and doesn't let me close the keyboard.

The Miles one opens up a number only keyboard and has a checkmark which lets me close the keyboard.

Wondering if something in the code is making this happen

I have added images below

```
package a00891437.set3s.comp3975.convertunits;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void onRadioButtonClicked(final View view){

        EditText mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MilesText);
        EditText kmText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.KilometersText);
        mText.setText("");
        kmText.setText("");

        if(view.getId()== R.id.KmToMButton) {
            mText.setEnabled(false);
            kmText.setEnabled(true);

        }
        if(view.getId() == R.id.MToKmButton){
            kmText.setEnabled(false);
            mText.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public void onClickedText (final View view){
        EditText kilometers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.KilometersText);
        EditText miles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MilesText);
        double km=  0;
        double m = 0;
        if(kilometers.isEnabled() == true){
            km = Double.parseDouble(kilometers.getText().toString());
            m = km * 0.621371;
            miles.setText(Double.toString(m));
        }

        if(miles.isEnabled() == true){
            m = Double.parseDouble(miles.getText().toString());
            km = m * 1.60934;
            kilometers.setText(Double.toString(km));
        }
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/screen">

    TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
        android:onClick="onClickedText"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/KilometersText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="134dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:enabled="false"

        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/MilesText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/KilometersText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/KilometersText"
        android:enabled="false"

        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Km"
        android:id="@+id/Kilometers"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/KilometersText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="M"
        android:id="@+id/Miles"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/MilesText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Kilometers"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Kilometers" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/radio_group">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Kilometers to Miles"
            android:id="@+id/KmToMButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/MToKmButton"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/MToKmButton"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Miles to Kilometers"
            android:id="@+id/MToKmButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/KmToMButton"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Kilometers"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Kilometers"
            android:checked="false"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>/>
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also had this problem once where the EditTexts didn't seem to listen to the XML. this fixed it for me:

```
 kmText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```